# Estructura de Base de Datos para Equivalencias de Unidades de Medida Articulos

Tags: sql, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy armando la estructura de una BD en SQL SERVER sobre Almacén e Inventarios.

El problema se me presenta en la tabla artículos ya que esta empresa vende cada Artículos por diferentes unidades de medida. Les planteo un ejemplo.

Vende artículos Escolares, los vende al por menor, por docena, por media docena, por por unidad.

Entonces la duda se me da al momento de organizar la estructura de la tabla Artículos, ya que este tiene varias unidades de medida, y también cada unidad medida tiene una equivalencia para poder manejar el inventario en el almacén.

Algún DBA con alguna experiencia en este tipo de proyectos, que me alguna idea de como poder administrar esa información, les estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Pues manejalo por unidades ¿no?

Si un cliente Jose compra 1 boligrafo registras 1 compra de 1 boligrafo
Pero si otro cliente compra 20 boligrafos registraras 1 compra de 20 boligrafos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un **nomenclador** para las unidades de medidas. Un **nomenclador** no es más que una **tabla** para guardar registros de conceptos generales. Ej: en tu caso tendrías un **nomenclador** llamado unidades de medida y en ese **nomenclador** podrías tener valores como:

**Cm**

**Km**

Todas las unidades de medidas que deberían ir ahí y entonces este **nomenclador** estaría asociado a través de una **llave foránea** a la **tabla artículos**.

Otro ejemplo:

Una persona tiene un **nombre** y un **país** aquí el **nomenclador** sería **país** que tendría todos los posibles países qué hay.

La ventaja que tiene usar nomenclador es es que evita inconsistencia en los datos y además se pueden hacer operaciones de creación, actualización y modificación de la información.